# akka-persistence (cqrs?) eventsourcing and side effects

Tags: scala, akka, event-sourcing, akka-persistence, akka-typed

I'm trying to figure out how to model the state of a remote "IoT" device with a persistent-actor, for example:

The user wants to turn on a light so we do the most logical.

1. User sends `OnCommand`
2. the persistent actor receives the command, generates a `LightTurnedOnEvent` and updates its state to `on`

So that makes sense but the problem here is the light is actually never turned on. Ok so then we build a `LightControlActor` that knows low level hardware-controll voodoo. This actor listen for `LightTurnedOnEvent` and when it gets it it does it thing and turnes on the light.

Awsome now we have a light turned on! But not happy. `LightTurnedOnEvent` is kind of lying here, the light is not turned on yet. Following this logic `LightTurnedOnEvent` should be generated by the `LightControlActor` and my persistent actor should generate some `SentRequestToTurnOnLight` but now this gets complicated for me with all the different semantics.

1. User sends `OnCommand`
2. Persistent actor recivecs `OnCommand` generate `RequestedLightTurnOnEvent` and set state to pending.
3. LightController picks up on the `RequestedLightTurnOnEvent` and tries to turn on the light on the external system.

So then what? Now how do I update the state of the persistent actor? Have the LightController send some veird command `SetStateToOnCommand`?

So how do I update the persistent state when the light is actually turned on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to go with something like "saga" for your events.

```
LightController: State idle
lightController ! OnCommand
    persist(LightTurnOnAttempted)
    lightControl ! LightTurnOnCommand
    become(pending)

LightControl:
lightControl ! LightTurnOnCommand
    performLightTurnOnAsyncFunction.map(_ => TurnOnLightCommand) pipeTo lightController

LightController: State pending
lightController ! TurnOnLightCommand
    persist(LightTurnedOn)
    become(initialized)
```

This gives you fine grained control. In case of crash and during the process of recovery, you can check whether the light was turned on or the `LightController` was in pending state. If it was in pending state, you can resend the `LightTurnOnCommand`.

Comment: I understand that your example is simplified but its getting at the core of my mental dilema a bit. As you describe it the `LightControl` in this case needs to respond back to the sender of the `TurnOnLightCommand` this works great if the only source of change is the `LightController` but if some one would turn on the light by flicking a physical switch our LightController state would be inconsistent.
What would be a good strategy there if we assume that the `LightControl` could pick up on external changes? Is that to have the `LightController` subscribe to the `LightControl` in some way?

Answer (score 0):

But you never know for sure that the light turned on, even if the HW controller says so, i.e. the bulb could be damaged.

The idea with events is the implications that they have in their *bounded context*. In your case, `LightTurnedOnEvent` is owned by the persistent actor and it has a strict meaning only in its context. From the owner actor's POV the light *should* be ON and a future `TurnOnCommand` would not change this state, a new event would not be emitted (it's idempotent).

If you want this event to have other implications, you need a Saga (or whatever you want to call it) that would react to this event and will send another command to another actor, in another context, i.e. in the HW context. This HW actor would emit its own events, relevant only in its context, i.e. `LightBulbCoupledToPowerSource` or something like this; it could even be named `LightTurnedOnEvent`, like the other, but in a separate *namespace*, very likely with other properties.

To better see this separation of concerns/contexts, we can imagine a situation in which a Saga, in reaction to `LightTurnedOnEvent` would send 3 commands to 3 different Light bulbs, in a big room for example.